# Who are we? The pure ones

Tags: riddle, science

We are not the wonders, though we were created by man

We are not the dwarfs, for our names are not proper

We are not the days, though they each contain one of our own

We are not the sins, for while our own kind exploits us, together we are pure.

In [science](/questions/tagged/science), we are the standard.

**Who are we?**

Comment: Could be sun but the sun is a dwarf stars

Comment: I've updated my answer below...

Comment: Added a hint (fifth line), and chose not to bother hiding it, because the [tag:science] tag didn't convey as much info to solvers as I hoped it would.

Comment: @Roland Can you comment on my answer Part II as to an example of why it doesn't fit please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> the seven base units of the SI system of units (meter, kilogram, second, ampere, kelvin, candela, and mole)

We are not the wonders, though we were created by man

> Its a man made system.

We are not the dwarfs, for our names are not proper

> These units are generally not capitalized.

We are not the days, though they each contain one of our own

> Days are made up of seconds, one of the base units.

We are not the sins, for while our own kind exploits us, together we are pure.

> These are the base ("pure") units, which are combined to make up the other derivative units in the SI system.

In science, we are the standard.

> They are the standard units used in the scientific world (as opposed to Imperial units used colloquially)

Comment: I have already suggested this answer [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/35772/20499)

Comment: I'd also note the repeated allusion to the number seven: the seven wonders, Snow White's seven dwarves, seven days in a week, and the seven deadly sins.

Answer (score 10):

"We are the standard"

Perhaps then, you are

> the seven standard SI units (metre, kilogram, second, ampere, kelvin, mole, candela).

We are not the wonders, though we were created by man

> Definitely named by man

We are not the dwarfs, for our names are not proper

> Self explanatory

We are not the days, though they each contain one of our own

> One of our own - seconds, contained in 'days'.

We are not the sins, for while our own kind exploits us, together we are pure.

> These units are pure together because the majority of equations (and their constants) are derived using these units. Other units do not work with these equations well, and the answer cannot be converted from one equation to another using the wrong units.

Comment: It appeared as if yours and @kayzeroshort 's answers came in almost simultaneously, thus I had a choice: since the explanation of the fourth line in the latter is exactly correct, I have chosen to accept it.
Most equations are not derived in any unit system: they describe the laws of nature to any observer in any culture.

Comment: @Roland For future reference, on the desktop site you can mouse over the part that says "answered 2 hours ago" to see the UTC timestamp. Inazuma's answer was 10 minutes earlier than kayzeroshort's.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I tried hovering over it, but apparently the 'answered' portion does not do so as well. This confirms my choice, as Inazuma explained their answer more than 5 minutes after kayzeroshort.

Answer (score 5):

You are:

> The seven [metals of antiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metals_of_antiquity): gold, silver, copper, tin, lead, iron and mercury.

1. We are not the wonders, though we were created by man

> They are often found naturally mixed with rock, in mineral deposits or alloys. Manmade processes are required to extract them in their pure forms.

2. We are not the dwarfs, for our names are not proper

> Most elements have names and symbols derived from the same root, typically Greek or Latin; the seven metals of antiquity use common English names while their symbols are derived from Latin roots (gold=Au, silver=Ag, copper=Cu, tin=Sn, lead=Pb, iron=Fe and mercury=Hg).

3. We are not the days, though they contain one of our own

> Wednesday is named after Odin, who is associated with the Roman god Mercury. Mercury is one of the metals of antiquity.

4. We are not the sins, for while our own kind exploits us, together we are pure.

> "Our own kind" refers to other elements; while each of the metals are pure in their elemental form, they can still be exploited by (e.g. chemically react with) other elements to form minerals and alloys.

Comment: Hm, never heard of these. Good answer, but a responsible riddler would never describe naturally occurring elements as "created by man".

Comment: Their grouping was created by man.

Comment: By that logic, anything we know to exist was created by man, correct? The stars? The planets?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>What are:</strike>

> The Seven Catholic Sacraments - each of the clues are of 7.

1- Not the wonders but created by man...

> Man came up with this list (I don't know, I'm assuming)

2- Not the dwarfs for names are not proper...

> The names of these are not proper nouns.

3- Not the days...

> [Eucharist](http://www.americancatholic.org/features/special/default.aspx?id=29) Occurs on Sunday

4- Not the sins...

> Reconciliation [same source](http://www.americancatholic.org/features/special/default.aspx?id=29) would fit.

After it was pointed out to me that this riddle was tagged with Science... My 2nd answer:

> [Branches of natural science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_science) (the 7 natural sciences)

Hint1:

> Created by man - yes

Hint2:

> Names are not proper - check

Hint3:

> Not the days, though the days contain one of our own... Astronomy is the study of planets, the days were derived from these: Monday comes from moon (one of the 7 planets of old world cosmetology), Tuesday comes from Mars, Wed Mercury, Thurs Jupiter, Fri Venus, Satur Saturn, and Sunday the sun

Hint4:

> Scientists (our own kind) exploit the sciences, and together they are pure... I can't quite explain my association to purity... save to say it makes sense to me... something like... together they encompass all real science of nature and anything having to do with natural science legitimately, would have to belong within one of the 7 branches... er... something...

Comment: I think this fits the clues rather nicely, but I just saw the second tag on the question: [science].

Comment: ...wish I had noticed it....

Comment: Your explanation of the 3rd hint is a bit of a stretch (the riddle would have said "inspired by" e.g., rather than "contain"). Your 4th is by your own account not a great fit, especially since "our own kind" ought to indicate other sciences, not man who participates in them.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are

> The Seven Muses: History, Poetry, Comedy, Tragedy, Music, Dance and Astronomy.

Hint1: We are not the wonders, though we were created by man

> Yes, created by man

Hint2: We are not the dwarfs, for our names are not proper

> Yes, names are not proper

Hint3: We are not the days, though they contain one of our own

> **Astronomy** can be considered, the days are derived from the planets' names. Or the past day is a **history**.

Hint4: We are not the sins, for while our own kind exploits us, together we are pure.

> Since together they are seven; in Greek Mythology, seven is the symbol of the Virgin. So can be considered as pure.

Comment: there were 9 muses; http://www.greekmythology.com/Other_Gods/The_Muses/the_muses.html

Comment: @JonMarkPerry yes, but when I refer this: http://www.fractiles.com/y7.html, They have listed as 7.

Comment: well i'd go and tell them they are wrong

Comment: Sorry, not the answer. The entire group falls into the [science] tag's realm, and the real answer will strongly agree with the last two clues.